# Saving wxPython scrolledcanvas contents to image

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been trying this for a bit and haven't found a solution that works for me

I have a `wx.scrolledcanvas` that I'm trying to save to an image, however when i use the answers I've found they all save only the visible portion of the canvas, and not the full canvas. Is there any way to save the entirety of the scrolled canvas to a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code such that what you are drawing in your `EVT_PAINT` handler can be called passing it the `wx.DC` to be drawn upon, and then call that from your paint handler with the `wx.PaintDC` or whatever you are currently using.  When you want to save it to an image call the same code passing a `wx.MemoryDC` with a `wx.Bitmap` selected into it.  When it's done the bitmap will have the same contents as the window, and you can then save it to a file or whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Actually was just coming back to respond that I had solved the problem in exactly that way.  Thank you